# android studio 4.0 cannot access com.example.projectname.javaname

Tags: android

I updated Android Studio some days ago. After I opened my project I found some codes that have new red underlines. I located my cursor and it says 'cannot access com.example.myprojectname.myjavafilename'. If I run the app it works well like before. But I hope to remove them to clean codes.

```
User post = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

only `dataSnapshot.getValue` part has a red underline. How can I remove them?

Comment: did u try Clean Project and Rebuild Project ??

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. In User.java some getter methods were missing. I added them so in MainActivity.java the redlines disappeared.

```
public String getTimer() {
        return timer;
    }
```